# ASP MVC http session for multiple users in one session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, session

Good day, struggling to understand asp mvc session. How can I store data against a single sessionID for multiple users. I will have two users sighed on, on the same machine from the same browser.

So one machine/browser and two active "windows", switch between tabs and the data overlap. The one page will override the next seeing that they share the same session.

Comment: What do you mean by "store data against a single sessionID for multiple users"? This is contradictory. A session ID refers to an individual user's session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET (all versions: WebForms, MVC, Web API, and more)...

- To store data for the life of the current request, use `HttpContext.Items`
- To store data for the life of the current session on a per-user basis, use `HttpContext.Session`
- To store data for the life of the application, which is shared by all users, use `static` (or `HttpContext.Application` - which is unoffically deprecated and a legacy from Classic ASP days)

Answer (score 0):

you can store data by user (profile), session or by application state.
I think application state will resolve your problem. you will have access to the information for all users

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx